# I get no smart caret in Aptana Studio

Tags: eclipse, navigation, titanium, aptana, camelcasing

I can't get word navigation on camelcase, underscore or periods in either Aptana or Titanium studios. Neither in PHP or Javascript. I do get it on hyphens though.
The only smart caret option I see in preferences is "Smart caret positioning at line start and end" in General->Editors->Text Editors. This have no effect on these.
Is there no way to enable better word navigation?

Btw, I'm using Mac. In case there are differences between Mac vs Pc Eclipse.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using Linux (Ubuntu) Aptana and it has the nice word navigation you described, then started using Max OS X for work and it does seem like the Mac version of Aptana and it seems to lack the same functionality (it only jumps over words separated by whitespace and not underscore or camelcase).

I know this is not an answer, but I can't post it as a comment since I don't have enough rep (wtf?).

Comment: Actually you were using the "Javascript Editor" on Linux, and then in OS X you are now using "Javscript Source Editor". In OS X there are no choices.

Answer (score 0):

Did a bit of searching (thanks to finding the right words to use from your question) and found this [bug report on the issue](https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD-6048), the solution (described in the final comment) is:

```
Go to System Preferences (OSX's not Eclipse/Aptana's) > Language & Text > Text 
set the "Word Break" dropdown to "English, United States (Computer)"
restart Eclipse/Aptana
```

Thanks for helping me find that - this has been bugging me for months. This may not fix for camelcase but definitely fixed it for periods for me on OSX 10.7 Aptana 3.4